# \hrule\hskip stretchability

Tags: rules

This

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\def\usrf{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hskip 0pt plus 1em minus 0pt\kern 0sp}
\begin{document}
\noindent A\usrf{}B C\linebreak DEFGH
\end{document}
```

results in that
[image: compilation result]

where the "underscore" between A and B is way longer than `1em`. How can I limit the maximum length of the `\hrule`, and why does it not work with the glue "stretchability" as given?

Comment: As soon as you assign nonzero stretchability to a glue, it will stretch without limit (at the expense of badness). Just like the space between B and C is stretching quite wide.

Comment: Now that you say it... So much for the explanation what is going on (+1). Now I need something "stretchable between length x and length y". Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are telling TeX to stretch a line to the line width, so it will obey your order.

Let's see a simpler example (plain TeX):

```
\hbox to\hsize{A\leaders\hrule\hskip 0pt plus 1em minus 0pt B C}

\noindent\the\badness

\bye
```

You get

[image]

The value printed by `\the\badness` is the badness of the last typeset box. Indeed, the terminal will also show

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 1
\tenrm A B C
```

As soon as a glue has nonzero stretchability, it will stretch as much as required, at the expense of badness. Just like it happens to the glue between B and C.

If you change the first line to

```
\setbox0=\hbox to\hsize{A\leaders\hrule\hskip 0pt plus 1em minus 0pt B C}
\showbox0
```

you'll find, in the log file,

```
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 38.11542
.\tenrm A
.\leaders 0.0 plus 10.00002
..\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
.\tenrm B
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
.\tenrm C
```

so the glue stretch ratio is 38.11542; this means that the first glob of glue (from `\leaders`) will become

```
38.11542 * 10.00002 = 381.15496
```

point wide and the second glob will become

```
38.11542 * 1.66498 = 63.46141
```

point wide.

Can I state “stretch at most X”? No, because of the rule above. With some computations it is of course possible.